# Data structure to query intersection of a line and a set of line segments

Tags: data-structures, computational-geometry

We want to pre-process a set $S$ of $n$ line segments into a data structure, such that we can answer some queries:
*Given a query line $l$, report how many line segments in $S$ does it intersect.*

It is required that the query should be done in $O(\log{n})$ time. The data structure itself should take up to $O(n^{2})$ storage and be built in $O(n^{2}\log{n})$ time. It is suggested that it should be done in dual plane.

I understand that the question may require me to look for the number of double wedge that the a query point is in, but I can't think of any efficient data structure to report such information. Any suggestions?

This question is basically a homework question from the textbook [Computational Geometry by de Berg et al](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=C8zaAWuOIOcC) (Question 8.15). I would like to apologize that this question may not be exciting to you.

Edit:
Yes it is in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. By query point I mean the query line dualised into a point on dual plane.

Comment: You refer to a query point, but I don't see any query point in the statement of the problem.

Comment: Line segments in $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: Did you have a look at https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/120384/approach-for-algorithm-to-find-closest-3-d-object-in-a-list-of-many-similar-obje/120633#120633 (if you consider your line a 'shape') and https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/117333/data-structure-to-report-all-axis-aligned-bounding-boxes-intersecting-an-axis-al/117477#117477 (if you consider lines as bounding boxes).

Comment: Please also see my answer here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/123349/number-of-double-wedges-containing-a-point/

Comment: The duals of the line segments are those wedges and the dual of the line is a single point. So you have to construct the arrangement of lines generated by the wedges and from this, point location in that planar subdivision. Nothing really appetizing...

Answer (score 1):

HERE is the solution I did in the homework but it still lose three points on:

(3 points) Construct the O(n^2) faces with proper intersection counts of each faces.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you the one who asked the original question?

Comment: It is a bit problematic to add an answer which you know is (slightly) wrong, without at least pointing out potential problems in it.

Comment: We'd prefer that you not use images as main content of your post. This makes your answer impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). It would be better to transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Comment: 1. No, I'm not the one who asks the question

2. for image since I use the color to correspond to figure information, I don't think it's convienet for me to transcribe text, or you can do it, and I will delete the answer if someone transcribes to txt

3. All answers are not perfect, and I think I point out why it's didn't totally right, I think others can just see it as reference but not the correct answer.

Comment: I upvoted as this seems to be a useful partial answer. According to the teacher part (a) and (b) are correct and part (c) is incorrect.